# Making Keras + Tensorflow code execution deterministic on a GPU

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm executing this code from https://www.kaggle.com/danijelk/allstate-claims-severity/keras-starter-with-bagging-lb-1120-596 on a nvidia geforce 960M.

```
''' 
Author: Danijel Kivaranovic 
Title: Neural network (Keras) with sparse data
'''

## import libraries
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

import pandas as pd
import subprocess
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import PReLU

## Batch generators ##################################################################################################################################

def batch_generator(X, y, batch_size, shuffle):
    #chenglong code for fiting from generator (https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-demographics/forums/t/22567/neural-network-for-sparse-matrices)
    number_of_batches = np.ceil(X.shape[0]/batch_size)
    counter = 0
    sample_index = np.arange(X.shape[0])
    if shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(sample_index)
    while True:
        batch_index = sample_index[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
        X_batch = X[batch_index,:].toarray()
        y_batch = y[batch_index]
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch, y_batch
        if (counter == number_of_batches):
            if shuffle:
                np.random.shuffle(sample_index)
            counter = 0

def batch_generatorp(X, batch_size, shuffle):
    number_of_batches = X.shape[0] / np.ceil(X.shape[0]/batch_size)
    counter = 0
    sample_index = np.arange(X.shape[0])
    while True:
        batch_index = sample_index[batch_size * counter:batch_size * (counter + 1)]
        X_batch = X[batch_index, :].toarray()
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch
        if (counter == number_of_batches):
            counter = 0

########################################################################################################################################################

## read data
train = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv')

## set test loss to NaN
test['loss'] = np.nan

## response and IDs
y = train['loss'].values
id_train = train['id'].values
id_test = test['id'].values

## stack train test
ntrain = train.shape[0]
tr_te = pd.concat((train, test), axis = 0)

## Preprocessing and transforming to sparse data
sparse_data = []

f_cat = [f for f in tr_te.columns if 'cat' in f]
for f in f_cat:
    dummy = pd.get_dummies(tr_te[f].astype('category'))
    tmp = csr_matrix(dummy)
    sparse_data.append(tmp)

f_num = [f for f in tr_te.columns if 'cont' in f]
scaler = StandardScaler()
tmp = csr_matrix(scaler.fit_transform(tr_te[f_num]))
sparse_data.append(tmp)

del(tr_te, train, test)

## sparse train and test data
xtr_te = hstack(sparse_data, format = 'csr')
xtrain = xtr_te[:ntrain, :]
xtest = xtr_te[ntrain:, :]

print('Dim train', xtrain.shape)
print('Dim test', xtest.shape)

del(xtr_te, sparse_data, tmp)

## neural net
def nn_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(400, input_dim = xtrain.shape[1], init = 'he_normal'))
    model.add(PReLU())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(200, init = 'he_normal'))
    model.add(PReLU())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, init = 'he_normal'))
    model.compile(loss = 'mae', optimizer = 'adadelta')
    return(model)

## cv-folds
nfolds = 5
folds = KFold(len(y), n_folds = nfolds, shuffle = True, random_state = 111)

## train models
i = 0
nbags = 5
nepochs = 55
pred_oob = np.zeros(xtrain.shape[0])
pred_test = np.zeros(xtest.shape[0])

for (inTr, inTe) in folds:
    xtr = xtrain[inTr]
    ytr = y[inTr]
    xte = xtrain[inTe]
    yte = y[inTe]
    pred = np.zeros(xte.shape[0])
    for j in range(nbags):
        model = nn_model()
        fit = model.fit_generator(generator = batch_generator(xtr, ytr, 128, True),
                                  nb_epoch = nepochs,
                                  samples_per_epoch = xtr.shape[0],
                                  verbose = 0)
        pred += model.predict_generator(generator = batch_generatorp(xte, 800, False), val_samples = xte.shape[0])[:,0]
        pred_test += model.predict_generator(generator = batch_generatorp(xtest, 800, False), val_samples = xtest.shape[0])[:,0]
    pred /= nbags
    pred_oob[inTe] = pred
    score = mean_absolute_error(yte, pred)
    i += 1
    print('Fold ', i, '- MAE:', score)

print('Total - MAE:', mean_absolute_error(y, pred_oob))

## train predictions
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_train, 'loss': pred_oob})
df.to_csv('preds_oob.csv', index = False)

## test predictions
pred_test /= (nfolds*nbags)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_test, 'loss': pred_test})
df.to_csv('submission_keras.csv', index = False)
```

I noticed that this code only sets the seed for numpy.

If I executed this code twice using a CPU, I would get the same results due to np.random.seed(123) on line #9

But I have executed it twice using a GPU obtaining two different results.

TensorFlow allows us to set a seed, used even on the GPU.

On Keras I haven't found this feature. Googling it, I've found that the dropout function admits a seed parameter. But I have not found a global gpu seed. Neither seed parameter on model.fit_generator, nor Dense.

My goal is to have the same results when code is executed twice.

Is it possible to set a seed on the GPU for TensorFlow using Keras?

How could this code be deterministic on a GPU?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, we can't control the random seed by adding `np.random.seed` when it comes to GPU. In fact, the randomness(non-determinstic) is a behavior of GPU.

The reason behind is that cuDNN(and othere CUDA stuffs) uses a non-deterministic algorithm to compute gradients, thus we can't determine anything.

For theano backend, you can add `deterministic` flag when using GPU, which leads a determine way, and a slower way.

For tensorflow backend, checkout [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938307/determinism-in-tensorflow-gradient-updates).

### References

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/850

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2652

Answer (score 1):

Many models can now be trained with perfect (bit-exact) floating-point reproducibility on GPUs using TensorFlow with Keras. And the range of ops that can operate deterministically on GPUs is increasing. Please see https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism for more information.